# CMake compiler standard include

Tags: c++, macos, cmake

I'm trying to understand how cmake is working.

I'm working on mac with homebrew package manager. I installed libpng with homebrew. The path to the header includes is in /usr/local/include which is also standard include header path for c++,g++,clang.

If I do for example something like this:

```
...
find_package(PNG)
target_link_libraries(mytarget PNG::PNG)
...
```

the headers are automatically found by compiler even if I throw away find_package(PNG). Cmake is just knowing that png.h, that I'm referencing in my cpp file, is in /usr/local/include.

But for some reason if I build my own lib and then install it in /usr/local/lib and /usr/local/include and then writing some find_library, find_path code to find headers and libraries of this my new fresh baked lib, it does not find my header mylib.h, that is also referenced in my cpp file. The error is that mylib.h is not found.

How does cmake handle the well knowing packages like PNG, Eigen, Boost and so on, so it finds headers automatically?

Comment: ***How does cmake handle the well knowing packages like PNG,*** There is a finder module for PNG.

Comment: I think you should read the documentation for find_package: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html

Comment: ***if I build my own lib and then install it in /usr/local/lib and /usr/local/include and then writing some find_library, find_path code to find headers and libraries of this my new fresh baked lib, it does not find my header mylib.h*** Did you generate your project for your library using CMake. If you don't you need to create a finder module for your library.

Comment: Yes the library is generated with cmake. 

The thing is my question has less to do with find_package. Why cmake just include headers for well known libraries like eigen, boost and png but not include headers for my library in compiler? They have the same path! Has cmake a problem with me? ^^

Comment: It has everything to do with find_package since that is how CMake finds the package..

Comment: But if I comment out find_package(PNG) for example it still finds the headers. Ok it complains about missing symbols but this because of course find_package didnt set anything.
If I do the same with my library it complains in first line of missing headers mylib.h

Comment: ***Yes the library is generated with cmake.*** You should have a libnameconfig.cmake in your binary folder where you built your lib. CMake needs to find this file. You can tell cmake-gui or ccmake where to look via the gui or command line parameters or possibly in your CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: @ptiza_v_nebe: Am I right that `find_package()` has **nothing** common with your problem, as you simply don't use it? If so, why you ever note it - it confuses about your problem a lot.

Comment: My problem arised from this use-case. I was just wondering why my library headers has to be explicitly linked with target_include_directories() and why I dont need to do this If I do find_package(PNG) for example

Comment: `why my library headers has to be explicitly linked with target_include_directories() and why I dont need to do this If I do find_package(PNG) for example` - So, you wander how `find_package(PNG)` plus `target_link_libraries(mytarget PNG::PNG)` tells CMake about *include directories*, am I right? `PNG::PNG` is an IMPORTED TARGET, corresponded to PNG library. This target has include directories, *assosiated* with it. When CMake links an executable with such target, it automatically adds these directories to the executable too.

Comment: Ok! I think it is nearer to what I'm looking for. I mean it sound like what I need. To prove that this .cmake file has to do with this directly I experimented and just for fun removed all content of FindPNG.cmake. For some reason cmake is still finding includes :(
Something similiar I tried to implement in mylib, also as FindXXX.cmake file, but it just didnt found the includes.

Comment: Maybe there is good tutorial with simple explanation but deep understanding? Something that will cover the topic Im talking about?

Comment: ***cmake is still finding includes*** This is because the includes for PNG are in a location that the your compiler already has as an include folder.

Comment: ***Something that will cover the topic Im talking about?*** I don't know of such a tutorial. I learned `CMake` by reading the documentation and trying the examples at the cmake-wiki. `CMake` is not something you can learn in a day. With that said tutorial requests are off topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: If your header files are in /usr/local/include the compiler should find them. Are you sure they are not in a subdirectory under /usr/local/include? Btw, CMake will look for headers in alternative directories when using include_directories or target_include_directories. Maybe you could just set include_directories(/usr/local/include) for any chance....

Comment: I tested linking the code directly with c++ which is on mac just some sym to g++. Something like c++ -lmylib main.cpp. It works fluently. C++ find my libs in standard path, but the same compiler in cmake do nothing. Maybe cmake uses other enviroment variables?